# Let $p(x) = x^3 + x + 1 \in \mathbb Z_2[x]$ and $E = \mathbb Z_2[x]/p(x)$. Factor $p(x)$ into linear factors in $E[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

Let $p(x) = x^3 + x + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ and $E = \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/p(x)$. Factor $p(x)$ into linear factors in $E[x]$.

Note that $p(t) = 0$, where $t = x + ⟨p(x)⟩$. You might also wish to show that $p(t^2) = 0$.

So far, I have that $E = \{a+bt+ct^2 : a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_2, t^3 = 1+t\}$ and I have shown that $p(t^2) = 0$. But I really do not know how to proceed from here.

I have in my notes that the solution is $p = [x + t][x + t^2][x + (t + t^2)] \in E[x]$ but I do not have any details on how this solution was obtained.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Many alternatives. You can try to prove that also $p(t^4)=0$ and then show that $t^4=t^2+t$. Or, as you already know that $x+t$ and $x+t^2$ are factors of $p$ in $E[x]$, you can find the last factor by (long) division of polynomials.